# Linq is not working with sitecore solr

Tags: linq, solr, sitecore

I am displaying search results using sitecore and solr. The scenario is if user search for something, search code first will check if that keyword is in "keywords" field of sitecore items, if it finds it will show the result and if it does not find, it will check for that keyword in title and description fields.

Now the problem is -
below condition is always false and never gives the result, in spite of values in the keywords field.

```
var Query = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                .Where(i => (i["keywords"].Contains(SearchQuery)));
```

where as the same query for title and description works fine

```
var Query2 = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                 .Where(i => (i["title"].Contains(SearchQuery) 
                          || i["description"].Contains(SearchQuery)));
```

for each sitecore item, I have title, description and keywords fields.

Below is the detail code snippet.

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public string SearchQuery { get; set; }

    List<WebSiteSearchResult> lst = new List<WebSiteSearchResult>();

    public IEnumerable<WebSiteSearchResult> SiteSearchResult()
    {
        var searchContext = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSearchContext();
        var Query = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(i => (i["keywords"].Contains(SearchQuery)));
        var result = Query.GetResults();
        if (result.TotalSearchResults != 0)
        {
            //some operations
        }

        else
        {
            var Query2 = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(i => (i["title"].Contains(SearchQuery) || i["description"].Contains(SearchQuery)));
            var result2 = Query2.GetResults();
            if (result2.TotalSearchResults != 0)
            {
                //some operations
            }
        }

        lst = lst.OrderBy(i => i.itemBoostingRatio).ToList();

        return lst;
    }
}

public class WebSiteSearchResult
{
    public string itemKeywords { get; set; }
    public int itemBoostingRatio { get; set; }
    public string itemTitle { get; set; }
    public string itemDescription { get; set; }
}
```

And, here my sitecore items: https://i.stack.imgur.com/liw59.png

Comment: Does your index files contains the keyword?

Comment: Can you check your queries directly on the index? You can find the queries in the search logs. Also check if the keywords field is in the index - and maybe check for the description field as well because your second query could be working on title only..

Comment: Try this: var Query = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                .Where(i => (i["keywords"].ToString().Contains(SearchQuery.ToString()))); as there might be problem of type mismatching

Comment: As Ben describes below you should use the fields of your WebsiteSearchResult class in a strongly typed way.  And also check that the actual field name is correct in Solr - for example title might actually be title_t in Solr. There's a basic guide on this here. http://www.bekagool.com/news-and-insights/sitecore-7-search-a-quickstart-guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your Sitecore item keywords are in a SLT field ("Loans, Car Loan, Bike Loan"), keep in mind that this field is a tokenized index. This means during storage processing, the query is split into tokens using whitespace and punctuation characters as delimiters, seen below:

[image]
[image]

Now if we search using `Equals` and `Contains`, the search log will give us the appropriate serialized query to test in solr:

**Equals**: `?q=keywordstest_t:("bike loan")`

- This is telling us to find any term in the list that matches this given value. If our term was `"scooter loan"`, we would not get any results back.

**Contains**: `?q=keywordstest_t:(*bike loan*)`

- This is telling us to return any result item where any term in the list contains any of the words/sub-words. This isn't search performant. If our term was `"scooter L"`, we would get a result back because of the **L**.

### A couple things to check

:
Is this value set to true in the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config`?

```html
<indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>
```

For best practices, create a new Search Result Item class that inherits from Sitecore's base `SearchResultItem`so that you can use it this instance to directly call the field property 'Keywords':

```
public class BasePageSearchResultItem : SearchResultItem
{
    [IndexField("keywords")]
    public string Keywords { get; set; }
}
```

The `Equals` query should be used to find **one** of these terms in the indexed field:

```
var Query = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
            .Where(i => i.Keywords.Equals(SearchQuery));
```

The result set will depend on the requirements, dictated by the search query `"scooter loan"` and given a sample item's keyword field value `"Loans, Car Loan, Bike Loan"`:

1. Search on *scooter* and *loan* separately, where each search query term is an exact match or is contained in an indexed term
2. Search on *scooter loan* as a whole

Comment: Hi Ben..Thanks a lot for your help. I got the solution when I replaced the field "keywords" with "keywords_t". But, will you please explain me why I have to add "_t" with any of the fields?

Comment: I believe this happens because you're not adding "Keywords" as an IndexField. This attribute makes sure that the property goes through the SolrFieldMap. In the case of this "single-line text" sitecore field, the return type is set to "text". Solr then knows to store this field with the fieldNameFormat of {0}_t. This also effects the way data is queried. Hence why the query is automatically appended with the above format.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben. You were a great help..got all the answers. :)